# Initial value never used, and method parameters not updating when code ran

Tags: c#

I want these method parameters, restart and winner to update a field in main. however, it doesnt seem to work because it says the value is never used. But I'm using it, so I don't understand;

```
'''
static void Restart(bool restart, bool winner, string[,] nums, bool[,] trueIfX, bool[,] trueIfO)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("would you liked to start a new game? Y/N");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        bool correctInput = false;

        do
        {

            if (input == "Y")
            {
                correctInput = true;
                restart = false;
                winner = false;
                nums[0, 0] = "1"; nums[0, 1] = "2"; nums[0, 2] = "3";
                nums[1, 0] = "4"; nums[1, 1] = "5"; nums[1, 2] = "6";
                nums[2, 0] = "7"; nums[2, 1] = "8"; nums[2, 2] = "9";
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this warning/error because `warning` is never actually used for something. Once you pass it to another function, use it in an if statement, etc, the warning/error will go away.

Think of it like having a builder as your employee and you give the employee a hammer. Yes you gave your worker the thing it needs, but now they're standing around waiting for you to use them for something.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to return `restart` and `winner` back to the method that had executed the `Restart()` ?

You can use the `ref` or `out` keywords to do it
`ref` means to pass parameter by reference. This allows called function to update the parameter value for caller
like

```cs
static void Restart(ref bool restart, ref bool winner)
{
restart = true;
}

static void Main()
{
var restartparam = false;
var winner = false;
Restart(ref restartparam, ref winner);
if (restartparam)
  RestartNow();
}
```

However having a lot of `ref` parameters can be weired.
So you can create a class and use it to pass data into the method.

like

```
class RestartOptions
{
public bool restart;
public bool winner;
}

static void Restart(RestartOptions opt)
{
opt.winner = true;
}

static void Main()
{
var options = new RestartOptions();
Restart(options);
if (options.winner)
  DispenseJackpot();
}
```

this allows you to modify `RestartOptions` class members and keep method signatures intact.